# How to add left right touch controls c# unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

So I created a really basic game for pc with a and d as left and right, however I want to port it to android installed the android pakage in unity and I don't know how to make it ti where when you touch the left side of the screen the object goes left and touch the right of the screen it goes right. current code from pc port

```
using UnityEngine;

public class player : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Rigidbody rb;
   public float force = 200f;
   public float left = -100f;
   public float right = 100f;
   
   
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Makes the ball move forward
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, force * Time.deltaTime);
        //Makes the ball move right and left
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(right * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(left * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the extents of the left side by using `Screen.width / 2`.  Left side is found by checking that the `x` value of your screen touch is below that half width value.

eg.

```
var halfWidth = Screen.width / 2;

var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
var touchPos = touch.position;

if (touchPos.x < halfWidth)
{
    Debug.Log("Left touched!");
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("Right touched!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much It worked, id upvote but not high enough

Answer (score 0):

Calculating touch position like @hijinxbassist's answer is the best way i think.

But you can use another solution like below either.

- Create Two Buttons and resize it to fill half of screen.
- Set button's anchor to each size of your screen. (In this case left and right side)
- Add button's onclick listener, and target to your code.

Comment: What is the benefit of buttons/canvas event vs the touch position

Answer (score 0):

This Will Work Properly With Android!

```
float side_speed = 100f;
float halfWidth = Screen.width / 2;
void Update()
{

            var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            var touchPos = touch.position;

            if (touchPos.x < halfWidth)
            {
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Left touched!");
                    transform.Rotate(0, 0, side_speed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
            }
            else if(touchPos.x > halfWidth)
            {
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Right touched!");
                    transform.Rotate(0, 0, -side_speed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
            }
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).